# How do I open an Android app straight to an activity that is not the main activity and later move to the main activity?

Tags: java, android, xml

The following is my mainActivity - up to the onCreate function, without the imports. I defined this as most of my activities parent. I want my app to open on the login activity - ao the user will login before using the app. After they log in, I want this activity to open.

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity
    implements NavigationView.OnNavigationItemSelectedListener {

public final String APP_TAG = "MyCustomApp";
public final static int CAPTURE_IMAGE_ACTIVITY_REQUEST_CODE = 1034;
public String photoFileName = "photo.jpg";
public final int MY_PERMISSIONS_REQUEST_CAMERA = 66;
public static final int MEDIA_TYPE_IMAGE = 1;
public static final int MEDIA_TYPE_VIDEO = 2;
private static final int CAMERA_REQUEST = 1888;

final int REQUEST_LOG_IN = 666;

FirebaseDatabase database = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance();
String m_Text;
User user = null;
DatabaseReference myRef;
DatabaseReference userRef;


@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
{

    //default text
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
    setSupportActionBar(toolbar);

    DrawerLayout drawer = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
    ActionBarDrawerToggle toggle = new ActionBarDrawerToggle(
        this, drawer, toolbar, R.string.navigation_drawer_open, R.string.navigation_drawer_close);
    drawer.setDrawerListener(toggle);
    toggle.syncState();

    tryGetUser();
}
```

The following is my LoginActivity - up to the onCreate function, without the imports. Which I want to be the first page to open

```
public class LoginActivity extends BaseActivity implements LoaderCallbacks<Cursor> {


final int RC_SIGN_IN = 101;

final int REQUEST_LOG_IN = 666;

/**
 * Id to identity READ_CONTACTS permission request.
 */
private static final int REQUEST_READ_CONTACTS = 0;

/**
 * Keep track of the login task to ensure we can cancel it if requested.
 */
private UserLoginTask mAuthTask = null;

// UI references.
private AutoCompleteTextView mEmailView;
private EditText mPasswordView;
private View mProgressView;
private View mLoginFormView;
private FirebaseAuth mAuth;

private GoogleApiClient mGoogleApiClient;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
{
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    mAuth = FirebaseAuth.getInstance();

    setContentView(R.layout.activity_login);
    // Set up the login form.
    mEmailView = (AutoCompleteTextView) findViewById(R.id.email);
    populateAutoComplete();

    mPasswordView = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.password);
    mPasswordView.setOnEditorActionListener(new TextView.OnEditorActionListener() {
        @Override
        public boolean onEditorAction(TextView textView, int id, KeyEvent keyEvent) {
            if (id == R.id.login || id == EditorInfo.IME_NULL) {
                attemptLogin();
                return true;
            }
            return false;
        }
    });
```

Comment: Code is a text. Please, post your code, not the screenshots

Comment: Is this better? It's my first question on stackoverflow so I'm still working out how to ask questions, what information is needed to answer my questions etc.

Comment: Much better. Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just set that activity as the launcher activity on the manifest instead of the default main activity.

PS: Please elaborate​ your question and post code not screenshots. How do you want help if you can't help yourself to be understood?